# How to implement audio ring for SIP outbound calls

Tags: audio, sip, phone-call, ringtone, outbound

Im using the android.net.sip class to make SIP calls

Although, I can make calls and capture all the audio events from the call session
Like ringing, busy, callconnected.....

How do i add the ringbacktone, and busy tone to the calls.

By default sipmanager does not play any of the normal audio you would expect to hear while placing a call.

Since the SIP Server does not send back any audio during a connection
i assume the audio must be played on the local phone.

I found mentions of Startringbacktone() but i dont see how to play it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is **Early Media**. Early media is simply media that is sent before a call is answered. Early media is typically supported by the use of the 183 Session In Progress response. Unlike a 180 Ringing response, 183 will contain SDP. This SDP is used to establish a media connection that carries those network tones and messages.

A good read is [SIP Media Management: Early Media vs. Late Media](https://andrewjprokop.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/sip-media-management-early-media-vs-late-media/)

Answer (score 0):

i just used MediaPlayer to play a sound between starting the call and when the OnCallEstablished is called.

As for a sound for busy I am not sure how to do that. Maybe test to see what is called back when busy is returned and then start a media player for that as well.